# load data with wrong datakind

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

### followed the sample by MS

https://github.com/tautvydasversockas/TaxiFarePrediction/blob/master/TaxiFarePrediction/Program.cs

---

Task

my project is to predict number of passagers at specific time such as

---

```
Input 
Year=2018,Month=10,Day=24,Type=normal
and the output is
Count = 2180
```

---

i have a simple csv file,around 1800rows

```
Day,Month,Year,Hour,Count,Type
24,10,2018,7,1860,normal
.
.
```

Count is the number of Passagers at 7 oclock 
Type is the type of date , such as 
normal= monday to friday 
Xmas,etc

---

Two Questions

i have no idea why the DataKind of day , month , year ,hour count ,is R4 ,shouldn't it be I4?

```
  public int Day;
  new TextLoader.Column("Day", DataKind.R4, 0),
```

Low accuracy
i have tried in "FastTree" , "FastForest"
the actual is 2860 people but result in 53 people
i have 1800 rows of data
that i  have chosen 1300 of them as training data
remain as test data for evaluate
and left one day for my predction

```
     public class TaxiTrip
            {
                [Column("0")]
                public float Day;

                [Column("1")]
                public float Month;

                [Column("2")]
                public float Year;

                [Column("3")]
                public float Hour;

                [Column("4")]
                public float Count;

                [Column("5")]
                public string Type;


            }

            public class TaxiTripFarePrediction
            {
                [ColumnName("Score")]
                public int predictCount;
            }
    _textLoader = mlContext.Data.CreateTextLoader(new TextLoader.Arguments()
                {
                    Separators = new[] { ',' },
                    HasHeader = true,
                    Column = new[]
                                {
//i prefer they are DataKind.I4
                                    new TextLoader.Column("Day", DataKind.R4, 0),
                                    new TextLoader.Column("Month", DataKind.R4, 1),
                                    new TextLoader.Column("Year", DataKind.R4, 2),
                                    new TextLoader.Column("Hour", DataKind.R4, 3),
                                    new TextLoader.Column("Count", DataKind.R4, 4),
                                    new TextLoader.Column("Type", DataKind.Text, 5),

                                }
                }
                );
```

**sorry for my poor english ,
thanks in advance**

Comment: I don't believe it supports much of the `I4` DataKind yet so it's safer to go with `R4`.  I usually just default to it myself. For your second question, it seems like you're not getting accurate results even trying different trainers. Can you post your pipeline code? There may be some extra transforms that help the accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *month* feature is ok (you can also convert it to categorical feature). It is correlated with temperature, day time, weather conditions etc. But *day* is not good without processing. You should generate new features with using *day* and *year* features like *weekend*, *holiday*. And there is a great sample for this problem, check it out:

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/Regression_BikeSharingDemand